# Orthonormal basis error diagonally dominant?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, inequality

I'm working on an error estimate for a numerical method, and in the process I've stumbled across the following abstract inequality which I think is true, but am having a hard time proving.

Suppose $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^N$ and $\{\psi_i\}_{i=1}^N$ are orthonormal bases of $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $(\phi_i,\psi_i) \ge 0$, and call the "error" between these basis vectors $e_i=\phi_i-\psi_i$. Is there a constant $C$ independent of N such that
$$
\sum_{i \neq j} (e_i,e_j) \le C \sum_i ||e_i||^2?
$$
I've written a matlab script to test it for thousands of random sets of orthonormal vectors and found no counterexamples so far for C=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that with out loss of generality we can assume $\psi_i$ are the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^N$. We construct $\phi_i$ as follows. Let $V$ be the vector $V := \sum_i^N \psi_i$, so we have $\langle V,\psi_i\rangle = 1$ and $\langle V, V\rangle = N$. Take

$$ \phi_i = -\frac{2}{N}V + \psi_i $$

so

$$ \langle \phi_i,\phi_j\rangle = \frac{4}{N^2}\langle V,V\rangle - \frac{2}{N}\langle V, \psi_i + \psi_j\rangle + \langle \psi_i,\psi_j\rangle = \delta_{ij} $$

and

$$ \langle \phi_i, \psi_i\rangle = 1 - 2/N \geq 0$$

if $N \geq 2$. ($\phi_i$ is obtained by reflecting $\psi_i$ over the plane $\{\langle\pi, V\rangle = 0\}$.)

Now,

$$ \langle \phi_i - \psi_i, \phi_j-\psi_j\rangle = \frac{4}{N} $$

So

$$ 4(N-1) = \frac{4}{N}\cdot (N^2 - N)= \sum_{i\neq j}\langle e_i,e_j\rangle \leq C_N \sum \|e_i\|^2 = 4 C_N $$

only if $C_N \geq (N-1)$.

Of course, using Cauchy-Schwarz one has $2\langle e_i,e_j\rangle \leq \|e_i\|^2 + \|e_j\|^2$, which implies that

$$   \sum_{i\neq j}\langle e_i,e_j\rangle \leq {n\choose 2} \frac{2}{N}\sum \|e_i\|^2  $$

So we have that the constant $C_N \leq (N-1)$.

And hence we have that the constant $C_N = (N-1)$ is sharp.

Comment: Ahh great construction! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another try:

First note that by considering $\{-\psi_i\}_{i=1}^N$, we can assume that $e_i=\phi_i+\psi_i$. (This is just for convenience.) We have for $i\not=j$ that$$(e_i,e_j)=(\phi_i,\psi_j)+(\phi_j,\psi_i)$$ and it follows that $$\sum_{i\not=j}(e_i,e_j)=2\sum_{i\not=j}(\phi_i,\psi_j) $$We have $\psi_i=\sum_{j=1}^N (\psi_i,\phi_j)\phi_j$ and so $$\|e_i\|^2=\sum_{j=1}^N |(\psi_i,\phi_j)-\delta_{ij}|^2=\sum_{j=1}^N |(\psi_i,\phi_j)|^2-2(\psi_i,\phi_i)+1.$$ It follows that $$\sum_{i=1}^N\|e_i\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N |(\psi_i,\phi_j)|^2-2\sum_{i=1}^N(\psi_i,\phi_i)+N.$$ The desired inequality with $C=1$ is equivalently to $$\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N |(\psi_i,\phi_j)|^2+N\ge 2\sum_{i=1}^N(\psi_i,\phi_i)$$ or $$\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N |(\psi_i,\phi_j)-\delta_{ij}|^2\ge 0.$$

Comment: Hey Steve thanks for the response. I think there are a couple issues with your reasoning, but it could be I'm just misunderstanding what you wrote. 1) if you set $e_i = \psi_i + \phi_i$, then I think it's the case that $||e||^2 = \sum_j |(\phi_i,\psi_j)+\delta_{ij}|$? 2) I think the RHS of the 2nd to last equation should be a double sum. 3) Because of this, the last eq is just a restatement of $||e||^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: Hi Nick, I think the single sum is fine but there does seem to be inconsistency in the signs. I will look at it more closely when I have time.

Comment: Statement is not true for C=1.

Comment: Part of the hypothesis is $(\phi_i,\psi_i)\ge0$, but you lose that when you replace $\psi_i$ with $-\psi_i$, no? Nick, which statement is not true for $C=1$ - are you saying you've found a counterexample to your original conjecture?

Answer (score 1):

I am more interested in the case where ***the two ordered bases have identical signs of oriented volume***, but we may study the problem with or without this additional requirement using a unified approach.

For convenience, let the two orthonormal bases be, instead, the columns of the orthogonal matrices $U=[u_1,\ldots, u_n]$ and $V=[v_1,\ldots,v_n]$ respectively ($n\ge2$). WLOG we may assume that $V=I_n$. Let $d_i=u_i-v_i$ and $e=(1,1,\ldots,1)$. We want to find the least possible $C\ge0$ such that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
0\le\delta_C(U)&:=& \frac12\left(C\sum_i \|d_i\|^2 - \sum_{i\not=j} \langle d_i,d_j\rangle\right)\\
&=& nC - C\sum_i\langle u_i,v_i\rangle + \sum_{i\not=j}\langle u_i,v_j\rangle\\
&=& nC - (C+1)\sum_i\langle u_i,v_i\rangle + \sum_{i,j}\langle u_i,v_j\rangle\\
&=& nC - (C+1){\rm tr}(U) + {\rm tr}(ee^T U)\\
&=& nC + {\rm tr}\left([ee^T - (C+1)I_n]U\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
for all $U$ with $\langle u_i,v_i\rangle\ge0$. Note that
$ee^T - (C+1)I_n = Q\Lambda Q^T$ where
$$
\Lambda = \begin{pmatrix}n-1-C\\&-(C+1)I_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
Q = \frac{1}{r}\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&-1&\ldots&-1\\
1&r-t&-t&\ldots&-t\\
1&-t&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&-t\\
1&-t&\ldots&-t&r-t
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $r=\sqrt{n}$ and $t=\frac{1}{r+1}$. So
$$
\delta_C(U) = nC + {\rm tr}\left(\begin{pmatrix}n-1-C\\&-(C+1)I_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}Q^TUQ\right).
$$

If $C\ge n-1$, we always have $\delta_C(U)\ge\delta_C(I_n)=0$. However, when $C<n-1$, the minimum of $\delta_C$ occurs at $U=U_{\rm opt}=Q(-1\oplus I_{n-1})Q^T = I-\frac2n ee^T$, with $\delta_C(U) = 2[C-(n-1)]<0$. Note that the columns of $U_{\rm opt}$ are exactly the basis found by Willie Wong and we have $\langle u_i,v_i\rangle\ge0$.

**What if we impose a further requirement that $\mathbf{\det U = \det V}$?** Since in the OP's problem context, $U$ is an estimate of $V$, in practice it may be reasonable to require that $\mathbf{\det U = \det V}$. Under our previous assumption (WLOG) that $V=I_n$, this additional requirement means $\det U=1$. In this case, we see that when $n-1-C\le(C+1)$, or equivalently, if $C\ge\frac n2-1$, we always have $\delta_C(U)\ge\delta_C(V)=0$. When $n-1-C>(C+1)$, if we let $R(\theta)$ denotes the rotation matrix by an angle $\theta$, then $\delta_C(U)=-[n-1-C-(C+1)]<0$ when $U = Q(R(\frac\pi2)\oplus I_{n-2})Q^T$. Therefore, we conclude that $\frac n2-1$ is the least possible $C$ that makes $\delta_C(U)\ge0$ for all $U$ such that $\det(U)=\det(V)$ and $\langle u_i,v_i\rangle\ge0$ for all $i$. Unfortunately, we do not know which nontrivial $U$ (i.e. some $U\not=V$) will make the inequality sharp. Without the constraint $\langle u_i,v_i\rangle\ge0$, $U = Q(R(\pi)\oplus I_{n-2})Q^T$ is a minimizer of $\delta_{\frac n2-1}$. It can be shown that this $U$ will make some $\langle u_i,v_i\rangle$ negative, however.

Answer (score 0):

The statement appears to be false, at least for C=1.

I wrote a little optimization script to find values that maximize the value of C=LHS/RHS, and it easily finds counterexamples. For example, the following set of 10 vectors has C=8.523:
$$
\\
    0.7449   -0.1554   -0.2566   -0.1677   -0.3110   -0.1738   -0.1967   -0.2552   -0.1312   -0.2812   
   -0.2923    0.7844   -0.1284   -0.1065   -0.2503   -0.2134   -0.2485   -0.2069   -0.1589   -0.1828 
   -0.1429   -0.2351    0.8301   -0.1749   -0.1849   -0.1480   -0.2192   -0.1936   -0.1031   -0.2287
   -0.2150   -0.2567   -0.1478    0.8380   -0.2066   -0.1578   -0.2133   -0.1680   -0.0756   -0.1294
   -0.1900   -0.2030   -0.2207   -0.1796    0.7393   -0.2527   -0.1869   -0.2995   -0.2257   -0.2361
   -0.2796   -0.2012   -0.2156   -0.2005   -0.2095    0.7855   -0.1406   -0.2357   -0.1624   -0.1790
   -0.2483   -0.1787   -0.1399   -0.1415   -0.2742   -0.2752    0.7760   -0.1274   -0.2534   -0.1826
   -0.2024   -0.2172   -0.1928   -0.2007   -0.1693   -0.1861   -0.2954    0.7745   -0.1689   -0.2356
   -0.2207   -0.1572   -0.1801   -0.2000   -0.1339   -0.1748   -0.0687   -0.1589    0.8643   -0.1691
   -0.1656   -0.2320   -0.1494   -0.2343   -0.2270   -0.2360   -0.2391   -0.1995   -0.1552    0.7831
$$

I've no idea what it is about these vectors that makes C so large.